# Ошибка в регулярном выражении php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка.

```
if (preg_match('\http(s)?://.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*', $qeustion['question'])) {
            echo "1";
        } else {
            echo "2";

        }
```

Но выдает такую ошибку

```
preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

Что может быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совершенно кривое регулярное выражение (шаблон). Во-первых, шаблон должен быть заключён в этот самый [разделитель](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) ("Delimiter") – символ, обозначающий начало и конец регулярки. Обычно это прямой слэш `/`. В вашем варианте это маленькая `\h` в начале, зачем-то экранированная. Добавляем слеши в начале и в конце:

```
preg_match('/\http.. /', $question..);
```

Сами символы слеша внутри шаблона нужно [экранировать](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.escape.php) - предварить обратным слешем, чтобы их не перепутать с окончанием регулярного выражения, например:

```
было  http(s)?://   стало http(s)?:\/\/
```

После этого вылезают другие проблемы – несоответствие закрывающих и открывающих скобок. Логика самого выражения подсказывает, что вы разбираете URL, поэтому я бы исправил начало так. Остальные макароны не распутывал:

```
if (preg_match('/(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=])*/', $qeustion['question'])) {
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "2";
}
```

p.s. «Вопрос» по-английски "question" – у вас, возможно, имя массива с опечаткой.

p.p.s. Ссылки на документацию на русском: ф-я [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php), [синтаксис регулярных выражений](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)